# В каких случаях используется спецификатор const при определении аргументов функции?

Tags: c++

Где и для чего может быть полезным определять функцию так, например:

```
int foo(const int a) { ... }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Два данных объявления функции

```
int foo(const int a);

int foo(int a);
```

объявляют одну и ту же функцию.

Квалификатор `const` в данном случае влияет лишь на определение этой функции. Если он присутствует в определении функции, то внутри функции соответствующий параметр является константной локальной переменной, и не может быть изменен.

Указание `const` в этом случае можно использовать разве лишь для документирования функции, указывая на то, что внутри функции используется реализация некоторого алгоритма, которая рассматривает значение этого параметра как константу.

Например, это может помочь при отладке. Допустим данная функция вызывает другую функцию с тем же самым аргументом

```
int foo(const int a)
{
    //...
    bar( a );
}
```

В таком случае вы можете быть уверены, что функция `bar`, вызывается с тем же самым значением аргумента, что и исходная функция `foo`, Это облегчит вам отладку функций, так как вы можете быть уверены, что до вызова `bar`, значение переменной `a` не изменилось, и функция `bar` вызывается с известным вам значением. То есть не надо исследовать код функции `foo` до вызова функции `bar`, чтобы определить, с каким значением последняя функция вызывается.

Answer (score 2):

Передача параметров в функцию
const удобен, если нужно передать параметры в функцию, но при этом надо обязательно знать, что переданный параметр не будет изменен.

```
void f1(const std::string& s);
void f2(const std::string* sptr);
void f3(std::string s);
```

В первой и второй функции попытки изменить строку будут пойманы на этапе компиляции. В третьем случае в функции будет происходить работа с локальной копией строки, исходная строка не пострадает.

Детальнее о const [тут](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2005/09/const-1.html) и [тут](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2005/09/const-2.html)